# Parsing XML and how to handle nested Arrays and Hashes

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm using this instance variable:

```
@response = HTTParty.get("http://www.bart.gov/dev/eta/bart_eta.xml")
```

I'm trying to parse the xml using rails 3.2:

```
<% @response.each do |r| %>
  <% r.each do |root| %>
    <%= root.class %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The output is

```
String Hash
```

I get "String Hash" for "root.class".  I don't understand how it can be "String Hash," I would like to implement another "each" method to go deeper in the xml layers.
What does "String Hash" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `@`response object is of the type `HTTParty::Response`.

It looks like it's wrapping an array with two values in it: the first value is a String, "root", and the second value is a Hash.

Since you have no line breaks in your ERB code, as you iterate through the array it is printing out String and Hash on the same line.

Try using `root.inspect` to dig deeper into what values you're actually iterating through.